# Запятая с несколькими И

Tags: запятые

...они не могут быть вписаны в существующие и устоявшиеся политические схемы(,) и идеологии.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно. Эти союзы И **не повторяющиеся** - соответственно никаких правил в отношении запятой тут не может быть.

Они **не соединяют** и не могут в принципе соединять в один ряд все перечисленные члены. Хотя бы потому, что это совершенно разнородные члены. 
(существующие и устоявшиеся) - что? - (схемы и идеологии).

В принципе эта ситуация не должна вызвать затруднений, если вдуматься в смысл фразы. 
**Старые и добрые бабушка и дедушка** - ну откуда тут запятой-то взяться.

Вот реально сложным может оказаться случай, когда неоднородность оказывается неочевидной или зависит от авторского восприятия.
**Это мои мама и папа и бабушка и дедушка** - запятых тут скорее всего не потребуется (вопреки oleedd), хотя все члены - однотипные части речи.

Для любителей доказательств.
Даже однородности (в понимании Розенталя) недостаточно для запятой.

8. Если два **однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом и, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом и с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится**: Вода давно сбыла в Тереке и быстро сбегала и сохла по канавам (Л. Т.) — парная группа сбегала и сохла с общим второстепенным членом по канавам, оба глагола несовершенного вида, в отличие от глагола-сказуемого совершенного вида сбыла; Задолго до рассвета Ильинична затопила печь и к утру уже выпекла хлеб и насушила две сумы сухарей (Ш.) — парная группа выпекла и насушила с общим обстоятельством времени к утру; Любка была девушка прямая и бесстрашная и даже по-своему же стойкая в тех случаях, если она кого-нибудь не любила (Ф.); Фыркает конь и ушами прядёт, брызжет и плещет и дале плывёт (Л); Первый звук его голоса был слаб и неровен и, казалось, не выходил из его груди, но принёсся откуда-то издалека (Т.); Пройти огонь и воду и медные трубы (Погов.); Он был молод и любознателен и считал нужным пользоваться каждым случаем для расширения кругозора. Ср. также: Тишь да гладь да Божья благодать (Погов.); Жить да поживать да добра наживать (Погов.).

Розенталь
http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=124#pp124

У меня всё.

(+)
Обсуждение, по моей просьбе открытое, моего примера и (что более интересно!) правила и примеров из Розенталя можно посмотреть тут.

http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6835

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97871/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus----).

Answer (score -1):

Без запятой.

Схема (п - прилагательное, с - существительное):

`(п и п) п (с и с)`

Для запятой нужно, чтобы было третье подряд существительное или третье подряд прилагательное возле `и`. А их только по два (см. схему).

Грубо говоря, если "сломать" смысл и поставить ещё одну `и` перед `политические` - то тогда перед `и` будет запятая:

`(п и п, и п) (с и с)`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97872/discussion-on-answer-by-oleedd----).